# Are there any advantages to giving money to random encounter NPCs?

Tags: far-cry-4

I occasionally encounter NPCs that can be interacted with to give money to, like this one:

[image: screenshot]

Is there an advantage to giving money? I haven't noticed it adding any karma level points.

Comment: he sure got an advantage then.

Comment: I've never seen this, And I the fact it doesn't give you karma, might be a bug.

Comment: This is where you see it is a game: in reality, chances are low that someone points a gun at you while giving you money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no advantage to you at all. It might make you feel good you gave a person another chance though :)